# NA in contingency table prevents chi-square test

Tags: r

So i am trying to do a chi-square test in R comparing bird population trends (stable or declining) with diet. Both are categorical variables and i'm using length function to count.

```
    con.table <- tapply(britishbirds$trend, list(britishbirds$trend, 
    britishbirds$diet), length)
    con.table
```

here's the output.

```
                 fish    generalist  invertebrates  mammals/birds plants/grains
decline            5         NA            32             4            14
increase/stable   18         10            46            10            24
```

I know I can't use NA in a chi-square test, i was hoping this function would output 0 but instead has put NA. Is there a way to change this to 0, or do i need to omit this category from the dataset?

Comment: I guess if you use `table(britishbirds$trend, britishbirds$diet)` you'll get a zero instead of `NA`.

Comment: yes that worked thank you!!!